# error in php month display

Tags: sql, pdo, wildcard

This php code display the months twice instead of a normal display. please help me out

```
    <?php
  /**
   * 
   * Populationg the month dropdown list dynamically
   * generating the months from January to december
   */
echo '<select name="monthz">';
for($m = 1;$m <= 12; $m++){
$month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m));
echo "<option value='$m'>$month</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `Day` parameter from your `mktime()` function, simply add it. I also edited your quote and double quote with concatenation

```
echo '<select name="monthz">';
for($m = 1;$m <= 12; $m++){
    $month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
                                         //^ this is the day
    echo '<option value="'.$m.'">'.$month.'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/sBiOxE)

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah you are welcome mate. Don't forget to upvote  answer, this is how StackOverflow works you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parameters from `mktime()`:

```
$month = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1, 2013);
```

Other than this, I cant see any reason why it would duplicate months.